# CSS background image no-repeat only working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

```
.myclass{
  background-image: url('http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/34/34164.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: 1.5%;

}
```

All my rows (tr) of the table have the class myclass: `<tr class="myclass">`
In Firefox the image is only displayed in all cells of the first column of the table but in chrome and opera all cells of table have this background image. What to do to make sure it shows only in the first column in chrome and opera as well?

Here is the html:

```
<table>
  <tr class="myclass">
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="myclass">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: share your HTML code as well

Comment: I've added the html as well.

Comment: put  class in first td

Answer (score 0):

Set it up like this

```
.myclass td:first-child {
  background-image: url('http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/34/34164.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: 1.5%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/brianmtreese/pen/XKwvqX

Comment: He has <th> as first <tr> and <td> as second <tr>. Your code works only if he adds the <td> tag instead of <th> tag in the first <tr> .

Comment: it could simply be added by adding `.myclass th:first-child` as well

Comment: `.myclass > :first-child`, if you care about efficiency (shouldn't we all?)

Comment: @skyline3000 You are right that the selector should contain a `>` but not for efficiency's sake (CSS selectors are parsed right to left, so the bottleneck is really the `:first-child` here). The problem is that otherwise all descendants inside those cells would also receive those styles!

Comment: @MrLister it absolutely has to do with efficiency, for the very reason you mentioned. The fact that a standalone `:first-child` is a slow selector only compounds the problem. Because browsers parse rules right-to-left, it will find every `:first-child` element on the page (which there will be many) and then has to traverse up the DOM to EVERY ancestor element looking for one with `.myclass`, all the way up to `<body>` and `<html>` before it stops. With the direct descendant selector `>`, the browser only has to look at the immediate parent element before it stops.

Comment: @MrLister the `:first-child` element could be anywhere under an element with `.myclass`, so for every single `:first-child` on the page the browser is going to check all parent elements searching for `.myclass`. That is terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.myclass` only first `th` & `td`

```css
.myclass{
  background-image: url('http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/34/34164.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: 1.5%;

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr >
    <th class="myclass">Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myclass">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```